# Explode empty line

Tags: php, string, explode

I am trying to explode empty line.

Here is my string variable:

```
$string = '
Hello,

Just test lines
Second test lines
';
```

I want these results:

```
$OUTPUT[0]='HELLO,';
$OUTPUT[1]='Just test lines
Second test lines';
```

My code:

```
$a = explode("\n\n",$string);
print_r($a);
```

My field results:

```
Array ( [0] => Hello, Just test lines Second test lines )
```

Comment: have you try it with only one `\n`?

Comment: Try `"\r\n\r\n"` and see if that works.

Comment: probably, `\r\n\r\n` instead of `\n\n`

Comment: @David Laberge ofcours i did i got Array ( [0] => [1] => Hello, [2] => [3] => Just test lines [4] => Second test lines [5] => )

Comment: cdhowie , lAbstractDownvoteFactory <-- thanks guys it's work fine

Answer (score 12):

This should do the trick:

```
$string = '
Hello,

Just test lines
Second test lines
';

$data  = preg_split("#\n\s*\n#Uis", $string);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its can be used when you take info from linux servers, :) thanks a lot agin.

Comment: In case of using PHPStorm, this is passing the code parse error validation: `'/\n\s*\n/Uis'`.

Answer (score 0):

throw a trim around your string, then explode it with the comma, then add the comma back on to the first element.

```
$arraything = explode(',', trim($string));
$arraything[0] = $arraything[0].",";
```

Comment: Trim isn't ideal when the spaces could be significative.